# How to Export and Import AD Users, Groups and Group Membership?

Tags: active-directory

Hallo, I want to copy my Active Directory Users, Groups and Group Memberships from one DC to another using csvde, where the machines are identical except for the only the name of the Domain and Machine. Note that each server is a DC and itself is the only member of the domain. The command I am using for export is:

```
csvde -f C:\exportAD.csv -m -n -o "primaryGroupID,lockoutTime" -j C:\Logs\
```

I then edit the csv file, deleting a few lines which will not import, and changing the Domain and Machine name, then import it on the second machine using:

```
csvde -i -f C:\exportAD.csv -k -j C:\Logs\
```

However, this does not the group memberships present in the original.

Any ideas?

-Frink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used:

```
csvde -f C:\Rename\export_AD.csv -m -n -o “primaryGroupID,lockoutTime” -j C:\Rename\Logs
Where:
  -f filename to export to
  -m do not export SAM values, e.g. objectSID
  -n do not export binary values
  -o exclude named columns
  -j folder to log to (produces csv.log, plus csv.err if any errors occured)
```

I then edited the export_AD.csv file as follows:

```
Delete the lines beginning:
o   “CN=Builtin …       (1 expected)
o   “CN=Infrastructure… (1 expected)
Delete all lines containing:
o   ,samServer,     (1 expected)
o   ,rIDSet,            (1 expected)
o   ,secret,            (4 expected)
o   ,rIDManager,        (1 expected)
Remove any ‘box’ (ASCII 13) characters in the text:
o   Unfortunately these cannot be searched for in Notepad
o   There may be one in the commas at the end of each of the last 50 lines in the file
Replace all instances of ‘PCOld’ with ‘PCNew’
o   Where PCOld is part of the machine name and domainname
```

Then import:

```
csvde -i -f C:\Rename\export_AD.csv -k -j C:\Rename\Logs
o   -i import
o   -f filename to export to
o   -k ignore non-serious errors (e.g. object, attribute or value already exists)
o   -j folder to log to (produces csv.log, plus csv.err if any errors occured)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is probably that the groups have different SIDs in each domain.  You do realise that you can not export passwords using CSVDE?

Have you considered the [Active Directory Migration Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=6f86937b-533a-466d-a8e8-aff85ad3d212&displaylang=en)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Passwords is not a problem as I'll have to change them all anyway and there are no external users yet. I did download the ADMT, but haven't used it as csvde seemed to work ok. I can add the group membership manually as there isn't many and this isn't going to be a regular occurrence.

Comment: The link to the AD Migration Toolkit is broken. [This link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc974332(v=ws.10).aspx) providers more info - seems you need to sign-up to MS Connect for it.